# Webapi (.NET Core) não tem ganho de performance quando utilzo async

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Estou implementando uma api de forma assíncrona, mas não vi muito ganho de performance. Utilizei o RESTful Stress for Chrome para fazer meus testes, simplemente não vi ganho de performance quando utilizo async. Pensei que isso iria aumentar a quantidade de requisições simultâneas.

Configuração usada
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Resultado usando async
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Resultado sem usar async
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Código usando async

```
public async Task<ObjectResult> Get()
{
    try
    {
        //usando ToListAsync() a performance foi pior, por isso usei Task
        //var result = await _dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        var result = await Task.FromResult(_dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList());

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return this.BadRequest("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Código sem usar async

```
public ObjectResult Get()
{
    try
    {
        var result = _dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToList();

        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return this.BadRequest("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas não deveria ter ganho de performance, porque a tarefa final é a mesma.. e você está esperando o resultado..
pelo seu exemplo você está consultando o banco.. e mesmo sync ou async sua api terá o mesmo trabalho para executar essas tarefas. O Async valeria a pena em um caso quando você não espera um resultado.. por exemplo.. fazendo um Insert, ou chamando outro serviço onde você não aguarda o resultado ou execução completa.